# Translation doesn't work in my symfony app

Tags: translation, symfony4, sulu

I'm trying to translate my back office into Italian. I use symfony 4 for my site, and sulu like librarie to have a small cms

I added a file "admin.it.json" in my translations folder, and my sulu_core.yaml file looks like this:

```
sulu_core:
locales:
    de: Deutsch
    en: English
    it: Italian
translations:
    - de
    - en
    - it
fallback_locale: '%default_locale%'
```

Unfortunately, my site is blocking on loading, and do not do anything else. I can not do anything, there is no mistake.

Even when I go on the link

```
localhost:8000/admin/translations?local=it
```

my translations are present, but the administration is not displayed.

Do you have an idea please?

Comment: When the _locale is in the URL with a route such as `@Route("/{_locale}/contact")` the code will be promoted to the translations.  https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/locale.html#the-locale-and-the-url

Comment: in my case I do not need to have the _local in my URL, ‘cause the link localhost:8000/admin/translations?local=it
 only serves to check if the json is read by the application

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration is correctly `config/packages/sulu_core.yaml`:

```
sulu_core:
    locales:
        de: Deutsch
        en: English
        it: Italian
    translations:
        - de
        - en
        - it
```

Then create a `translations/admin.it.json`

```
{
    "sulu_tag.tags": "Tags It"
}
```

Clear the cache then and go to your Profile change the `System` language from `en` to `it`.

See for translation keys the `admin.en.json` files in the https://github.com/sulu/sulu repository.